# Dialogflow list does not work on Google Assistant the first time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, chatbot, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, api-ai

My Dialogflow agent is using an 'Actions on Google Rich Message' List response object to display options on the Google Assistant platform.

The list options work perfectly when testing on the Dialogflow console. However, when testing through the Google Assistant Simulator or Google Assistant app on a mobile device, the list option does not work on the first try. It works only when selecting an option the second time.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code or the JSON you're using to reply? Are you doing this through webhook fulfillment?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the `actions_intent_OPTION` event in an intent that can handler the user selection from list.

[image: add event]

You can access the value from the parameter using the `#actions_intent_OPTION.OPTION`

[image: fetch value from list selection]